# Find $a$ and $b$ so that $f$ is differentiable everywhere

Tags: calculus, nonlinear-system

The piecewise function is $$f(x)=\begin{cases} ax^3 & x\leq 2 
\\ x^2+b, & x>2 \end{cases} $$

First I plug in the 2 into both functions and set them equal to each other 
$$ 2^2+b=a(2)^3$$
$$4+b=8a$$
$$\frac{1}{2}=a-b $$
Then I take the derivative of both functions and repeat 
$$3ax^2=2x+b$$
$$12a=4+b$$
$$a+b=\frac{1}{3} $$

I then subtract both equations from each others 
$$\frac{1}{2}=a-b $$
$$-\frac{1}{3}=a+b$$
to get $b=\frac{1}{6}$ and then $a=\frac{2}{3}$ but when I checked my answer I was wrong, I don't know where I went wrong

Comment: You made an error in going from the line "$4+b=8a$" to "$\tfrac12 = a-b$". (you didn't divide $b$ by $8$). Also, the derivative of "$x^2+b$" is "$2x$", not "$2x+b$".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on the right track but you  have made some algebra and derivative  mistake in finding your $a$ and $b$.

Note that $$12a=4 \implies a=1/3$$

Also $$ 4+b=8a \implies a=1/2 +b/8$$

You can take it from here.

Answer (score 1):

$4+=8$ is correct. what should you get from this Eric?

Also $3^2=2$. But why Eric?

Comment: for the first one should it be that the line of 8a is = to b shifted 4 units

Comment: sure. I meant that your arithmetic on the line following this line I quoted wasn't correct. Simple arithmetic mistake is all there is.

Answer (score 1):

You made an error saying that

$$(x^2+b)' = 2x+b$$

The correct way to get the value of $b$: Function $f(x)$ must be continuous at $x=2$. 
You will get:

$$8a = 4+b \quad (1)$$

And the derivative must also be continuous:

$$12a = 4$$